# Joi validate individual fields of nested schema

Tags: joi

I have a nested schema setup like this:

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  first_name: Joi.string().required(),
  last_name: Joi.string().required(),
  address: Joi.object().keys({
    street: Joi.string().required(),
    zip: Joi.number().required(),
    state: Joi.string().required(),
    country: Joi.string().required()
  }).required(),
})

var options = { abortEarly: false };

var result = Joi.validate({}, schema, options);
```

When running this, `result.error` will return the message:

```
[
  {message: '"first_name" is required', path: 'first_name' }, 
  {message: '"last_name" is required', path: 'last_name' },
  {message: '"address" is required', path: 'address' }
]
```

As you see, the `address` field is not expanded. I don't want to get a message that the whole address field is missing. Instead, I want to be informed about the individual items in the address schema missing. When I don't make `address` explicitly required, the items in it don't get validated against `required()` at all. The nested field validation seems to work only on the entire nested schema object level, not on the individual items within the schema level. How do I make it work with the individual nested schema items?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "skeleton" object works. 
Working example [here](https://runkit.com/ashcoolman/5930b4c701ec840012913836/branches/master).

```
import Joi, {
  string,
  number,
  object
} from "joi";

var schema = object({
  first_name: string().required(),
  last_name: string().required(),
  address: object({
    street: string().required(),
    zip: number().required(),
    state: string().required(),
    country: string().required()
  })/*.required(), <= Not needed */
})
var skeleton = { address: {} };

var options = { abortEarly: false };

var validate = data => {
  var newData = Object.assign({}, skeleton, data);
  return Joi.validate( newData, schema, options);
}
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(validate({}).error.details, null, 2)
);
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "message": "\"first_name\" is required",
    "path": "first_name",
    "type": "any.required",
    "context": {
      "key": "first_name"
    }
  },
  {
    "message": "\"last_name\" is required",
    "path": "last_name",
    "type": "any.required",
    "context": {
      "key": "last_name"
    }
  },
  {
    "message": "\"street\" is required",
    "path": "address.street",
    "type": "any.required",
    "context": {
      "key": "street"
    }
  },
  {
    "message": "\"zip\" is required",
    "path": "address.zip",
    "type": "any.required",
    "context": {
      "key": "zip"
    }
  },
  {
    "message": "\"state\" is required",
    "path": "address.state",
    "type": "any.required",
    "context": {
      "key": "state"
    }
  },
  {
    "message": "\"country\" is required",
    "path": "address.country",
    "type": "any.required",
    "context": {
      "key": "country"
    }
  }
]
```